# Which attribute(s) should be used to hide drop-down menus in pure CSS?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, cross-browser

When coding drop-down menus, these attributes normally appear:

```
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE8 and lower */
    display: none;
    left: -999em;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

To hide the drop-down, what are the differences between using **visibility**, **opacity**, **display** and negative **positioning**? Should all four of them be used together, or are some of these attributes just redundant when combined? What's the most effective way to do it, and why?

Comment: Read this: http://alistapart.com/article/dropdowns

Comment: display: none; is more than enough

Comment: just so you know, questions containing "best" are often opinion based. in this case, its not so bad, as most people agree, but try to avoid them in the future

Comment: I agree with @SamDenton. Generally, "best practices" questions are off-topic at SO, but despite the phrasing I think this is a specific enough question about coding that would useful Q&A material to have here. It's more about what the differences are between the attributes. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: @AdiInbar much better with the edit

Comment: @AdiInbar tks for the edits. It's much clear now.

Answer (score 0):

to hide/show the menu, you usually just use display.
with opacity you won't hide it completely but see a little through it and see what's behind it.
i'm not sure what visibility is for in this example.

Comment: I know that _display: none_ and _visibility: hidden_ combined they hide an element from both screenreaders and browsers (h5bp.com/u). Just using _visibility: hidden_ hides an element visually and from screenreaders, but maintains the layout.